# Simplifying this Further

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2x(x^2-3)^{10} + 20x(x^2+3)(x^2-3)^9$$

I would like to double check my answer (if anyone can double check this please)

Please simplify the top

Comment: Double check with ... what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2x(x^2-3)^{10} + 20x(x^2+3)(x^2-3)^9=2x(x^2-3)^9(x^2-3+10(x^2+3))=2x(x^2-3)^9(11x^2-27)$$

Comment: This answer looks right to me, and someone downvoted. (Maybe to discourage folks doing the complete problem.)

Comment: @coffeemath Most probably, it is just my unsupportive wife.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

If I replace $x^2-3$ with $y$ then you're problem becomes
$$2xy^{10} + 20x(x^2+3)y^9$$
Can you factorise this? You should see that there is a common factor of $y^?$. Once you take that factor out, replace $y$ with $x^2-3$. Ignore the common factor of $(x^2-3)^?$, expand and simplify the other factor.